# Remove Detach and Find Articles button from Case Articles related list

Tags: case, setup, articles

I have a profile where I have given only read only permission for Articles. And I have the related list on Case Pagelayout. Now with these permissions, I see a "Detach" link and "Find Articles" on the related list. I need to remove these buttons.

Is there a way to do it?

Thanks in Advance
Phaniraj N

Answer (score 0):

If the related article list in Cases page layout has a "wrench" icon to edit it, then you can edit the related list and the button as well on the list can be removed. I think since that related list is "not editable" you could only achieve that using VF